# Ansible: Loop over list of fileglobs

Tags: ansible

I have a list in ansible that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "src_files": "/tmp/files/**/*",
        "dest_dir": "/home/user1"
    },
    {
        "src_files": "/tmp/files2/**/*",
        "dest_dir": "/home/user2"
    }
]
```

Now I want to loop over every element in that list and then over file in the corresponding fileglob, and copy it to `dest_dir`.

I understand how to use `copy` with `with_fileglob`, but how can I unnest this list of fileglobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to include *with_fileglob* from a separate file. For example

```
- include_tasks: copy-fileglob.yml
  loop: "{{ my_list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: outer_item

$ cat copy-fileglob.yml
- copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "{{ outer_item.dest_dir }}"
  with_fileglob: "{{ outer_item.src_files }}"
```

(not tested)